# MySQL - how to SELECT existing datetime value in ISO 8601

Tags: mysql, datetime, iso8601, date-conversion

I have usual datetime 'enddate' column where values - `2018-09-13 23:59:59`

I need to select the one in ISO 8601 format - `2018-09-13T23:59:59`

Timezone set in /etc/my.cnf - `default_time_zone='+00:00'`

There are some answers here at Stack I tried without a success
`SELECT DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y-%m-%dT%TZ')` 
- works for function NOW() but not for existing value

`SELECT DATE_FORMAT('enddate', '%Y-%m-%dT%TZ') AS date_formatted` - returns NULL for me

So I'm looking for a real MySQL query to convert/select a value from existing datetime column, for example

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT('enddate','%Y-%m-%dT%TZ') FROM tablename WHERE id=17 ;
```

such a query should return something like
`2018-09-13T23:59:59` - but actually returns `NULL`

Thx for any ideas to try/correct to get a valid ISO 8601 value,

---

ANSWER is simple but thanks to comments below/ This query works without the quotes to define enddate as a column

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(enddate,'%Y-%m-%dT%TZ') FROM tablename WHERE id=17 ;
```

so I leave this question for other readers

Comment: `‘enddate’` is a string, `enddate` is a column. Drop the quotes

Comment: [Here is demo](http://rextester.com/PVHARE23109) showing that your code will work if you heed the above comment.

Comment: yes, you both are right, I just missed the quotes.